# Dynamically assign .onRelease to movieclip, with dynamic url too AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Sure this will be a simple fix, and I'm just not seeing the wood for the trees.  I have a movie with a movieclip called scroller_mov.  Inside it are 15 movieclips named pic1 thru pic15.

My code is on one frame, on the same level as scroller_mov.  Just want to dynamically assign a click action to the pic1 - pic15 movieclips!  have tried hardcoded links and dynamic, but no joy!  Everything else works fine.  Thanks if you can help!

```
stop();

lv_obj = new LoadVars();

lv_obj.load("flash_carou_data2.php");

lv_obj.onLoad = function(success):Void{
product_mod.product_model = this.product_models;

var products_data:Array = product_mod.product_model.split(",");
scroller_mov.prodmod1 = products_data[0];

for (i=0;i<15;i++){
    products_data[i] = products_data[i].split("&");
    scroller_mov["prodmod" + (i+1)] = products_data[i][0];
    scroller_mov["prodprice" + (i+1)] = products_data[i][3];
    scroller_mov["pic" + (i+1)].loadMovie(products_data[i][2]);

    scroller_mov["pic" + (i+1)].onRelease = function  () {
        getURL("http://www.mysite.com");
        //getURL(products_data[i][1]);
    }
};
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it just the way you do it in your code - but you have to wait for the `loadMovie()` to finish.  When you load a MovieClip, all its properties are erased upon successful completion.

Set an interval to check for your MovieClip's `getBytesLoaded()` and `getBytesTotal()` methods, then assign the onRelease function when the clip is fully loaded.  Here's a quick example, you can just copy and use the same `checkLoaded` function:

```
_root.test = _root.createEmptyMovieClip ("test01", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
_root.test.loadMovie ( "test.swf");

_root.checkLoaded =  function (clip) { 

   var bytesLoaded = clip.getBytesLoaded();
   var bytesTotal = clip.getBytesTotal();
   if (bytesLoaded > 0 && bytesLoaded == bytesTotal) trace ("loaded");
   else return;
   clearInterval (_root.interv);

   clip.onRelease = function () {
        trace ("release");
        getURL("http://www.google.com"); 
    } 
}

_root.interv = setInterval( _root, "checkLoaded", 100, _root.test);
```

You can assign the interval to any variable, it doesn't need to belong to `_root`.  Make sure the first parameter of `setInterval` is the object where the `checkLoaded` method is contained, and the last parameter is the MovieClip you are loading into.

Comment: @brain And I love comments from new users re-affirming how much they enjoyed the answer. So thanks, that's great too! Makes us believe you accepted the answer for a very good reason and it actually helped solving your issue. :)